# Using global variables in a PHP loaded through jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, load

I am using a jquery function to call a getdata.php file like this -

```
       $("#tasks").load("getdata.php?choice=" + $("#projects").val());
```

The getdata.php echoes back results dynamically to the callee.

```
<?php   //getdata.php                       
    global $user_id; //<--These variables are defined in the callee file
    global $con;
    $choice=$_GET['choice'];
    $query="SELECT task_id,title from tasks where user_id=$user_id AND proj_id=$choice";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if((mysqli_num_rows($res))!=0)
    {
        while (list($task_id, $title) = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
          {
           echo "<option value=$task_id>$title</option>";   
      }
     }
     else
     {
        echo "<option>No current Tasks</option>";
     } ?>
```

Is there any way by which I can access the variables in the callee file from here. I tried using global as would normally be the case with included files but that's not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using $_SESSION variables to set variables that are available to both your callee file and getdata.php.

Comment: @PrateekUdenia NP Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as accepted to assist future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in the request ? `Something like

```
 $("#tasks").load("getdata.php?choice=" + $("#projects").val() + "&user_id=" + user_id;
```

(How to pass PHP variables to js as already got a lot of answers on SO)

then in getdata.php

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
```

for the DB connection, you can create a kind of config file that you include on every script

config.php

```
function getDBConnection() {
   blah...blah ...
   return $con;
}
```

in getdata.php as in every script that need it :

```
require_once yourpath/config.php;
$con = getDBConnection();
```

For security reasons, if your config file contains passwords, login , etc ... put it outside
your web directory.